# Get value from Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am looking for solution for my problem:-
I have a Tuple like:-

```
MY_TUPLE_CHOICE = (
    ('INS', 'Instagram'), 
    ('FAB', 'Facebook'),
    ('YOU', 'Youtube'),
    ('TWT', 'Twitter'),
)
```

Now First I want to get Tuple Value with Key inside Value for example if a key is **'YOU'** it should return me **('YOU', 'Youtube')**.

Second I want to get individual value within Tuplevalue for a key for example key is **'YOU'** it should return me **'Youtube'**.

Comment: Is the data coming from somewhere else? If not, you could model it differently, e.g. use [\[Python\]: namedtuple() Factory Function for Tuples with Named Fields](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: I can't modify the existing data. I know Dictionary is the best option here but currently, I have to achieve same using Tuple.

Comment: @Avi Can you explain why you can't convert the data into a dictionary?  The requirement seems rather odd.  It's like saying "I want to drive that nail, but I'm only allowed to use a soldering iron.  I know the hammer lies right next to me, but I can't use it."

Comment: You simply need to iterate over the tuple and compare the values against what you want. You should learn stuff like this as part of any basic tutorial or book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have to work with a `tuple` and cannot change the data structure to a `dict` you can use the following:

```
MY_TUPLE_CHOICE = (
    ('INS', 'Instagram'),
    ('FAB', 'Facebook'),
    ('YOU', 'Youtube'),
    ('TWT', 'Twitter'),
)

def get_from_tuple(my_tuple, key):
    return next((y for x, y in my_tuple if x == key), None)

print(get_from_tuple(MY_TUPLE_CHOICE, 'YOU'))  # Youtube
print(get_from_tuple(MY_TUPLE_CHOICE, 'ASD'))  # None
```

That said, note that the requirements of your task and the type of data you have are *ideal* for the use of a `dictionary`. In case you become allowed to use one, just convert your tuple with `dict(MY_TUPLE_CHOICE)`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use a dictionary instead of a tuple:

```
d = dict(MY_TUPLE_CHOICE)
```

You can now access the values for each key by item access, e.g. `d['YOU']` will return `'Youtube'`.

If you really need the first part, i.e. return the `(key, value)` pair for a given `key`, you can simply use `(key, d[key])`.

Comment: That I am not allowed to change. Can't I get the value from the existing one.

Comment: @Avi I hereby give you permission to change the data type. :)  If you are receiving the tuple as an input, simply convert it to a dictionary first.

Comment: I have to do it using Tuple that's why I am not allowed to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can built a dict with dict comprehension.

```
abbr_dict = {item[0]: item for item in MY_TUPLE_CHOICE}
```

For first operate:

```
>>>abbr_dict["YOU"]
('YOU', 'Youtube')
```

For second operate

```
>>>abbr_dict["YOU"][1]
'Youtube'
```